# Canvas game frame rate drop (30fps), also randomly stuttering/janking

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I've been having a big issue with performance for the game I'm writing. For some reason while playing, the game stutters and seems to either draw the same frame twice or just skip drawing for that frame. As you can see in the image, for some reason when this jank/stutter happens the FPS drops to 30 and the frame time is twice as long. These stutters happen extremely frequently, every 1-5 seconds. I've tested for memory leaks nothing unusual, tested for garbage collection, nothing unusual. They are called using requestAnimationFrame in the update() function. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lasquish/zcs2Lkoa/7/) that I put together. Just right click the output, go to timeline and profile for 20 seconds. You will see FPS drops to 30 randomly. On the fiddle most of the code is from external files that I added and is not important with the issue. I added a line at line 579 to show where the important code starts. The two functions that are causing the issue are the moveAllGameRectangles(); renderTheGameObjects(); which are on lines, 1180 and 1098 on the fiddle. If you could take a look at those two functions and tell me if you see anything that could be improved performance wise that would be great. I removed collision detection for testing purposes. I`ve had this problem for months so any help would be extremely great!

```
(function() {
var c = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ds = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

var theMaxWidth = c.width / 4.5;

if (c.height === 1743 || c.height === 1744 || c.height === 1740) {
    var gameVelocity = 60;
} else {
    var gameVelocity = 70;
}

var so = Math.round(c.height / gameVelocity + 65);

var halfVelocity = gameVelocity * 4;
var halfVelocityModulus = gameVelocity * 2;

var modulusNumber = 17;

var OPENING = 0
var LOADING = 1
var BUILD_MENU = 2
var BUILD_MAP = 3
var PLAYING = 4
var LOST = 5
var SETTINGS = 6

assetsLoaded = [];
cargoAnimation = [];
gameObjectsArray = [];
menuObjectsArray = [];
movingMenuObjectsArray = [];
assetsToLoad = [];
whatToMove = [];
gameObjectsPlayingArray = [];
movingGameObjectsArray = [];
lossObjectsArray = [];
settingsObjectArray = [];
messages = [];
theMaxArray = [];
messagesHighScore = [];
settingsTextArray = [];
loadTheFontBeforeArray = [];

randomNumber = 0;
randomGameNumber = 0;

var touchAllowed = false;
var collisionOrNot = false;
var gameRunning = true;
var loaded = false;
var settingsItem1Checked = false;

var practiceModeOn = false;
var interval = null;
var gameInterval = null;

assetsLoaded = 0;
doneLoading = false;

var gameState = OPENING;

var cargo = new Image();
cargo.src = "../www/img/cargo.png";
cargoAnimation.push(cargo);

var menuObjects = new Image();
menuObjects.src = "../www/img/loadingScreenSpriteSheet.png";
assetsToLoad.push(menuObjects);

var gameObjects = new Image();
gameObjects.src = "../www/img/gamePlayingSprites.png";
assetsToLoad.push(gameObjects);


function loadHandler() {
    assetsLoaded++;
    if (assetsLoaded === assetsToLoad.length) {
        touchAllowed = true;
        gameState = BUILD_MENU;
    }
}



window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.addEventListener("touchstart", touchUpHandler, false);
});
c.addEventListener("touchstart", touchdownhandler, false);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    gameState = LOADING;
});

// backgroundSquare menu
var bSquare = Object.create(mainObject);
bSquare.sourceX = 0;
bSquare.sourceY = 0;
bSquare.sourceWidth = 256;
bSquare.sourceHeight = 264;
bSquare.width = c.width / 2 + c.width / 10;
bSquare.height = c.height / 3;
bSquare.x = c.width / 5;
bSquare.y = c.height / 2 - c.height / 6;
menuObjectsArray.push(bSquare);
lossObjectsArray.push(bSquare);

// loss menu
var lSquare = Object.create(mainObject);
lSquare.sourceX = 0;
lSquare.sourceY = 360;
lSquare.sourceWidth = 228;
lSquare.sourceHeight = 92;
lSquare.width = c.width / 2 - c.width / 35;
lSquare.height = c.height / 9;
lSquare.x = c.width / 3 - c.width / 14;
lSquare.y = c.height / 3 + c.height / 25;
lossObjectsArray.push(lSquare);

// play button
var play = Object.create(mainObject);
play.sourceX = 256;
play.sourceY = 0;
play.sourceWidth = 66;
play.sourceHeight = 64;
play.width = c.width / 5;
play.height = c.height / 9;
play.x = c.width / 3 - c.width / 14;
play.y = c.height / 2 + c.height / 100;
menuObjectsArray.push(play);
lossObjectsArray.push(play);

// settingsButton
var settings = Object.create(mainObject);
settings.sourceX = 322;
settings.sourceY = 0;
settings.sourceWidth = 66;
settings.sourceHeight = 64;
settings.width = c.width / 5;
settings.height = c.height / 9;
settings.x = c.width / 3 + c.width / 5 + c.width / 150;
settings.y = c.height / 2 + c.height / 100;
menuObjectsArray.push(settings);
lossObjectsArray.push(settings);

// logo
var logo = Object.create(mainObject);
logo.sourceX = 0;
logo.sourceY = 265;
logo.sourceWidth = 228;
logo.sourceHeight = 92;
logo.width = c.width / 2 - c.width / 35;
logo.height = c.height / 9;
logo.x = c.width / 3 - c.width / 14;
logo.y = c.height / 3 + c.height / 25;
menuObjectsArray.push(logo);


// firstButton
var button1 = Object.create(mainObject);
button1.sourceX = 0;
button1.sourceY = 257;
button1.sourceWidth = 103;
button1.sourceHeight = 120;
button1.width = c.width / 4;
button1.height = c.height / 4;
button1.x = 0;
button1.y = c.height - c.height / 6;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(button1);

// secondButton
var button2 = Object.create(mainObject);
button2.sourceX = 103;
button2.sourceY = 257;
button2.sourceWidth = 103;
button2.sourceHeight = 120;
button2.width = c.width / 4;
button2.height = c.height / 4;
button2.x = c.width / 4;
button2.y = c.height - c.height / 6;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(button2);

// thirdButton
var button3 = Object.create(mainObject);
button3.sourceX = 207;
button3.sourceY = 257;
button3.sourceWidth = 103;
button3.sourceHeight = 120;
button3.width = c.width / 4;
button3.height = c.height / 4;
button3.x = c.width / 4 + c.width / 4;
button3.y = c.height - c.height / 6;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(button3);

// fourButton
var button4 = Object.create(mainObject);
button4.sourceX = 309;
button4.sourceY = 257;
button4.sourceWidth = 103;
button4.sourceHeight = 120;
button4.width = c.width / 4;
button4.height = c.height / 4;
button4.x = c.width / 4 + c.width / 4 + c.width / 4;
button4.y = c.height - c.height / 6;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(button4);

// theGameCharacter
var theGameCharacter = Object.create(mainObject);
theGameCharacter.sourceX = 0;
theGameCharacter.sourceY = 380;
theGameCharacter.sourceWidth = 60;
theGameCharacter.sourceHeight = 60;
theGameCharacter.width = c.width / 6;
theGameCharacter.height = c.height / 11;
theGameCharacter.x = c.width / 24;
theGameCharacter.y = c.height * .75 - c.height / 15;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(theGameCharacter);


var settingsMenu = Object.create(mainObject);
settingsMenu.sourceX = 256;
settingsMenu.sourceY = 64;
settingsMenu.sourceWidth = 66;
settingsMenu.sourceHeight = 64;
settingsMenu.width = c.width / 6;
settingsMenu.height = c.height / 11;
settingsMenu.x = c.width / 20;
settingsMenu.y = c.height / 35;
settingsObjectArray.push(settingsMenu);

var settingsMenuNonChecked = Object.create(mainObject);
settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceX = 256;
settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceY = 180;
settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceWidth = 182;
settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceHeight = 50;
settingsMenuNonChecked.width = c.width / 2;
settingsMenuNonChecked.height = c.height / 13;
settingsMenuNonChecked.x = c.width / 10;
settingsMenuNonChecked.y = c.height / 5;
settingsObjectArray.push(settingsMenuNonChecked);

timerMessage = Object.create(messageObject);
timerMessage.x = c.width / 2;
timerMessage.y = c.height / 10;
timerMessage.font = getFont();
timerMessage.fillStyle = "#3000ff";
timerMessage.visible = true;
messages.push(timerMessage);

timerMessageHighScore = Object.create(messageObject);
timerMessageHighScore.x = c.width / 2;
timerMessageHighScore.y = c.height / 5;
timerMessageHighScore.font = getFont();
timerMessageHighScore.fillStyle = "#3000ff";
timerMessageHighScore.visible = true;
messagesHighScore.push(timerMessageHighScore);

settingsText = Object.create(messageObject);
settingsText.x = c.width / 1.6;
settingsText.y = c.height / 4.7;
settingsText.font = getSmallerFont();
settingsText.fillStyle = "#3000ff";
settingsText.visible = true;
settingsText.text = "Practice Mode"
settingsTextArray.push(settingsText);

loadTheFontBefore = Object.create(messageObject);
loadTheFontBefore.font = getSmallerFont();
loadTheFontBefore.fillStyle = "#3000ff";
loadTheFontBefore.x = -c.width;
loadTheFontBefore.y = -c.height;
loadTheFontBefore.visible = false;
loadTheFontBeforeArray.push(loadTheFontBefore);


function getFont() {
    var size = c.width / 20 * 2
    return (size | 0) + 'px neuropolitical rg';
}

function getSmallerFont() {
    var size = c.width / 30 * 2
    return (size | 0) + 'px neuropolitical rg';
}


update();

function update() {

    ds.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);


    //console.log(cargoAnimation.length, gameObjectsArray.length, menuObjectsArray.length, movingMenuObjectsArray.length, assetsToLoad.length, whatToMove.length, gameObjectsPlayingArray.length, movingGameObjectsArray.length, lossObjectsArray.length, settingsObjectArray.length, messages.length)

    req = requestAnimationFrame(update, c);

    switch (gameState) {

        case LOADING:
            loadHandler();
            break;

        case BUILD_MENU:
            moveAllRectangles();
            renderMenuObjects();
            beforeLoadTheFont();
            break;

        case BUILD_MAP:
            moveAllGameRectangles();
            renderTheGameObjects();
            checkForCollisonsRectangles();

            break;

        case PLAYING:
            break;

        case SETTINGS:
            renderSettingsObjects();
            renderSettingText();
            break;
    }
}


function checkForCollisonsRectangles() {
    for (var i = 0; i < movingGameObjectsArray.length; i++) {

        var collisionOrNot = hitTestRectangle(theGameCharacter, movingGameObjectsArray[i]);

        if (collisionOrNot && movingGameObjectsArray[0].y > theGameCharacter.y + theGameCharacter.height - c.height / 80) {
            collisionOrNot === false;
            return;
        }

        if (collisionOrNot) {
            stoptimer();
            resettimer();
            touchAllowed = true;
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(req);
            displayRestartMenu();
            gameRunning = false;
            logHighScore();
            showHighScore();
            return;
        }
    }
}

function logHighScore() {
    console.log(practiceModeOn)
    if (practiceModeOn === false) {
        theMaxArray.push(timerMessage.text);
        Array.max = function(theMaxArray) {
            return Math.max.apply(Math, theMaxArray);
        };
        var maximum = Array.max(theMaxArray);
        timerMessageHighScore.text = maximum
    }
}

function showHighScore() {
    console.log(practiceModeOn)
    if (practiceModeOn === false) {
        if (messagesHighScore.length !== 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < messagesHighScore.length; i++) {
                var message = messagesHighScore[i];
                if (message.visible) {
                    ds.font = message.font;
                    ds.fillStyle = message.fillStyle;
                    ds.textBaseline = message.textBaseline;
                    ds.textAlign = 'center';
                    ds.fillText(message.text, message.x, message.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function renderSettingText() {
    if (settingsTextArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < settingsTextArray.length; i++) {
            var message = settingsTextArray[i];
            if (message.visible) {
                ds.font = message.font;
                ds.fillStyle = message.fillStyle;
                ds.textBaseline = message.textBaseline;
                ds.textAlign = 'center';
                ds.fillText(message.text, message.x, message.y);
            }
        }
    }
}

function beforeLoadTheFont() {
    if (loaded === true) {
        return;
    }
    if (loadTheFontBeforeArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < loadTheFontBeforeArray.length; i++) {
            var message = loadTheFontBeforeArray[i];
            ds.font = message.font;
            ds.fillStyle = message.fillStyle;
            ds.textBaseline = message.textBaseline;
            ds.textAlign = 'center';
            ds.fillText(message.text, message.x, message.y);
        }
    }
    loaded = true;
    console.log("runn")
}

function displayRestartMenu() {
    if (lossObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < lossObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = lossObjectsArray[i];
            ds.drawImage(
                menuObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
        }
    }
}

function touchUpHandler() {

    touchX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - c.offsetLeft;
    touchY = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - c.offsetTop;

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, play)) {


        if (gameState === BUILD_MENU) {
            movingMenuObjectsArray = [];
            startstoptimer();
            gameState = BUILD_MAP;
            gameRunning = true;
            touchAllowed = false;
        } else {
            if (touchAllowed === true) {
                movingMenuObjectsArray = [];
                startstoptimer();
                movingGameObjectsArray = [];
                update();
                gameState = BUILD_MAP;
                gameRunning = true;
                touchAllowed = false;
            }


        }
    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, settings)) {
        if (touchAllowed === true) {
            gameState = SETTINGS;
            if (!gameRunning) {
                update();
                movingGameObjectsArray = [];
            }
            gameRunning = true;
        }
    }


    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, settings)) {
        if (touchAllowed === true) {
            gameState = SETTINGS;
            if (!gameRunning) {
                update();
                movingGameObjectsArray = [];
            }
            gameRunning = true;
        }
    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, settingsMenu)) {
        if (gameState === SETTINGS) {
            gameState = BUILD_MENU;
        }
    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, settingsMenuNonChecked)) {
        console.log(settingsItem1Checked)
        if (settingsItem1Checked === true) {
            console.log("doing")
            if (c.height === 1743 || c.height === 1744 || c.height === 1740) {
                gameVelocity = 60;
            } else {
                gameVelocity = 70;
            }
            modulusNumber = 17;
            settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceY = 180;
            settingsItem1Checked = false;
            practiceModeOn = false;
            return;
        }
        if (settingsItem1Checked === false) {
            console.log("doing")
            if (c.height === 1743 || c.height === 1744 || c.height === 1740) {
                gameVelocity = 120;
            } else {
                gameVelocity = 140;
            }
            modulusNumber = 30;
            settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceY = 128;
            settingsItem1Checked = true;
            practiceModeOn = true;
            return;
        }

    }



}



function touchdownhandler() {

    touchX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - c.offsetLeft;
    touchY = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - c.offsetTop;

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, button1)) {

        theGameCharacter.x = c.width / 23;

    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, button2)) {

        theGameCharacter.x = c.width * .25 + c.width / 23;

    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, button3)) {

        theGameCharacter.x = c.width * .5 + c.width / 23;

    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, button4)) {

        theGameCharacter.x = c.width * .75 + c.width / 23;

    }

}

function renderTheGameObjects() {

    if (movingGameObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < movingGameObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = movingGameObjectsArray[i];
            sprite.y += sprite.vy;
            ds.drawImage(
                gameObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
            if (sprite.y > c.height - c.height / 6) {
                var removeThis = sprite;
            }
        }
    }

    removeTheMenuObject(removeThis, movingGameObjectsArray);

    if (messages.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            var message = messages[i];
            if (message.visible) {
                ds.font = message.font;
                ds.fillStyle = message.fillStyle;
                ds.textBaseline = message.textBaseline;
                ds.textAlign = 'center';
                ds.fillText(message.text, message.x, message.y);
            }
        }
    }
    if (gameObjectsPlayingArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gameObjectsPlayingArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = gameObjectsPlayingArray[i];
            ds.drawImage(
                gameObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
        }
    }
}


function hitTestPoint(pointX, pointY, sprite) {
    return pointX > sprite.left() && pointX < sprite.right() && pointY > sprite.top() && pointY < sprite.bottom();
}

function renderMenuObjects() {
    if (menuObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < menuObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = menuObjectsArray[i];
            ds.drawImage(
                menuObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
        }
    }
}

function renderSettingsObjects() {
    if (settingsObjectArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < settingsObjectArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = settingsObjectArray[i];
            ds.drawImage(
                menuObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
        }
    }
}

function moveAllGameRectangles() {
    gameInterval = gameInterval + 1;
    if (gameInterval % modulusNumber === 0 || gameInterval === 1) {
        var randomGameNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        if (randomGameNumber === 1) {

            //the green game object
            var leftSideSpriteGame1 = Object.create(mainObject);
            leftSideSpriteGame1.sourceX = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.sourceY = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.sourceWidth = 310;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.sourceHeight = 64;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.width = c.width * .75;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.height = c.height / 14;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.x = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.y = -65;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(leftSideSpriteGame1);

        }

        if (randomGameNumber === 2) {

            //the red game object
            var leftSideSpriteGame2 = Object.create(mainObject);
            leftSideSpriteGame2.sourceX = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.sourceY = 64;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.sourceWidth = 207;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.sourceHeight = 64;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.width = c.width * .5;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.height = c.height / 14;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.x = 0
            leftSideSpriteGame2.y = -65;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(leftSideSpriteGame2);

            var rightSideSpriteGame2 = Object.create(mainObject);
            rightSideSpriteGame2.sourceX = 310;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.sourceY = 64;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.sourceWidth = 103;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.sourceHeight = 64;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.width = c.width * .25;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.height = c.height / 14;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.x = c.width * .75;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.y = -65;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(rightSideSpriteGame2);
        }

        if (randomGameNumber === 3) {
            //the blue game object
            var leftSideSpriteGame3 = Object.create(mainObject);
            leftSideSpriteGame3.sourceX = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.sourceY = 128;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.sourceWidth = 103;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.sourceHeight = 64;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.width = c.width * .25;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.height = c.height / 14;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.x = 0
            leftSideSpriteGame3.y = -65;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(leftSideSpriteGame3);

            var rightSideSpriteGame3 = Object.create(mainObject);
            rightSideSpriteGame3.sourceX = 207;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.sourceY = 128;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.sourceWidth = 207;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.sourceHeight = 64;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.width = c.width * .5;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.height = c.height / 14;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.x = c.width * .5;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.y = -65;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(rightSideSpriteGame3);
        }
        if (randomGameNumber === 4) {
            //the pink game object
            var rightSideSpriteGame4 = Object.create(mainObject);
            rightSideSpriteGame4.sourceX = 104;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.sourceY = 192;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.sourceWidth = 310;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.sourceHeight = 64;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.width = c.width * .75;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.height = c.height / 14;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.x = c.width * .25;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.y = -65;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(rightSideSpriteGame4);
        }
    }
}



function moveAllRectangles() {
    interval = interval + 1;
    if (interval % 60 === 0 || interval === 1) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        if (randomNumber === 1) {

            var seg1 = Object.create(segment1);
            seg1.width = c.width * .75;
            seg1.height = c.height / 14;
            seg1.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg1.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg1);

        }
        if (randomNumber === 2) {

            var seg2 = Object.create(segment2);
            seg2.width = c.width * .5;
            seg2.height = c.height / 14;
            seg2.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg2.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg2);

            var segL = Object.create(segment3);
            segL.width = c.width * .25;
            segL.height = c.height / 14;
            segL.x = c.width * .75;
            segL.y = -c.height / 14;
            segL.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(segL);

        }
        if (randomNumber === 3) {

            var seg3 = Object.create(segment4);
            seg3.width = c.width * .25;
            seg3.height = c.height / 14;
            seg3.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg3.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg3);

            var seg3R = Object.create(segment5);
            seg3R.width = c.width * .5;
            seg3R.height = c.height / 14;
            seg3R.x = c.width * .5;
            seg3R.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg3R.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg3R);

        }
        if (randomNumber === 4) {

            var seg4 = Object.create(segment6);
            seg4.width = c.width * .75;
            seg4.height = c.height / 14;
            seg4.x = c.width * .25;
            seg4.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg4.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg4);
        }
    }

    if (movingMenuObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < movingMenuObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = movingMenuObjectsArray[i];
            sprite.y += sprite.vy;
            ds.drawImage(
                menuObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
            if (sprite.y > c.height) {
                var removeThis = sprite;
            }
        }
    }
    removeTheMenuObject(removeThis, movingMenuObjectsArray);

}

function removeTheMenuObject(objectToRemove, array) {
    var i = array.indexOf(objectToRemove);
    if (i !== -1) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

function renderGameObjects() {
    if (gameObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        ds.drawImage(
            image,
            0, 0,
            414, 736,
            0, 0,
            414, 736
        );

    }
}
}());
```

[image]

Comment: It runs just fine on my laptop... maybe the performance issue is related to your computer?

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. It tends to stutter on occasion. Try refreshing the page and trying again. I have ported this to my android phone and my ios phone, along with my laptop and I get the same performance. The worst of them all is when i ported it to my ios phone.

Comment: Why is this tagged `ios`?

Comment: Because I am using Cordova to port this game to the ios phone. That is where i am also testing for performance. I'll remove the tag now. Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow wasn't meant for code optimization but for issues: "I want to do A, I tried B but C doesn't work". I believe this would be better suited on Stack Exchange Code Review, where people are more likely to have time to invest.

Comment: On a sidenote, I saw that you put a `setTimeOut("display()")` call in the fiddle. You should never use that as setTimeOut will have to evaluate the string as a script before running it. Just write `setTimeout(display)` instead.

Comment: ok, thanks for your input.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil. Code optimization is fair game on SO. ;-)

Comment: @markE. I am using setTimeout at the beginning of the program to change the game state. On line 838 you can see the requestAnimationFrame function that is control the refresh rate of the game. What line were you originally talking about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No optimisation needed**

I have just had a good look at the code and profiled it on fiddle. The good news is that you do not need to optimise the code, you are running at about 5% of max.

In the time line image you posted you can see that your code does next to nothing most of the time. Optimising is always good, but for your app increasing iddle time from 95% to 96% is not worth the bother.

**Optimal loading V Overload**

I have include a image that shows how the optimal loading for 60fps a second should look like on the timeline and then how an over loaded frame rate looks like that can just manage 30frames per second and is jumping frame rates from 30-20 because there is too much being done.

[image: good V bad timelines]

Compared to OP's

[[image: OP timeline][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLPTd.png)

**Look elsewhere**

When you compare them you can see there is practically nothing happening in your game, most of the frame is idle time, Your code could do near 1000 Fps  and still have spare time. The problem for your frame rate is elsewhere, either something is taking CPU time or you are sharing the GPU with something the is hogging bandwidth and RAM.

If you have the dev tools open all the time and you do lots of `console.log` that can have a big impact. Keep `console.log` calls out of code when you don't need them any more.

Without more info on the device you are run it on and what other apps the device is running I can not give you a definite solution. Shut down as many apps and services as you can till you notice an improvement. Its most likely just one bad app thats causing it.

**Now the bad News**

You say that you are not concerned about GC. Well you should be very concerned if you ever wish to expand the game. Using the CPU profiler your games is generating enough unwanted RAM  to have GC be between 2-5% of your total processing time (that excludes the idle time) You are lucky you have time to spare and some, but GC has a mind of its own and is one of the main causes of inconsistent frame rates. In comparison the code that had the good V bad (100,000 lines of code) will never peak GC above 0.1% if it shows up at all.

Think of it this way, every time you run some code that creates an `Array` or `Object`, or when you use `new Something()` or `Object.create(foo)` you are creating something that has to be cleaned up. If you do that every frame you are constantly generating garbage in your RAM. The result is a constant load for GC which will just get worse as the complexity of the code increases. GC for a game loop should never go above 0.5% and if done well it should stay way below 0.1%

**Never use new in the game loop**

Same for `foo = []`, `obj = {}`, `obj = Object.create(blah)` especially the last one. Not only are you requesting more ram for an object that already has RAM, but `Object.create` is about the slowest way to create a new object that javascript has. It gets worse, not only is it the slowest way to create an object it creates the slowest objects to access and use. Forget you even knew that function existed.

**Example of bad memory usage.**

```
// creates an object 
function GameThing(a1,a2,a4,a4){
    this.a1 = a1;
    this.a2 = a2;
    this.a3 = a3;
    this.a4 = a4;
    this.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; // create a new array in game loop BAD
}
function rand(){return Math.random()};);
var gameThing;
function mainLoop(){
    // using new in the main loop BAD
    gameThing = new GameThing(rand(),rand(),rand(),rand()); // dumps the old RAM 
                                                            // for GC and uses some
                                                            // more for the next loop.
}
```

**How it should be done**

```
// creates an object 
function GameThing(a1,a2,a4,a4){
    this.a1 = a1;
    this.a2 = a2;
    this.a3 = a3;
    this.a4 = a4;
    this.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; 
}
function reuseGameThing(thing,a1,a2,a3,a4);
    thing.a1 = a1;
    thing.a2 = a2;
    thing.a3 = a3;
    thing.a4 = a4;
    thing.data[1] = 0;  // don't create a new array. The memory has be set
    thing.data[2] = 1;  // aside for it already, why dump it to reset the values
    thing.data[3] = 2;  // just overwrite the old values. The time save 
    thing.data[4] = 3;  // from needless GC hits is well worth he little
    ...                 // extra time for set each item
    ...
    thing.data[9] = 10;
}

function rand(){return Math.random()};);
// create the object ONCE only. It create a ram buffer for your data
// that should not need to be deleted for the life time of the current game state
var gameThing = new GameThing(rand(),rand(),rand(),rand());
function mainLoop(){
    // Instead of dumping the old reuse its memory
    reuseGameThing(gameThing,rand(),rand(),rand(),rand()); 
    // so much quicker as there is no need to find and assign new RAM and
    // GC will not be called 
}
```

Do not worry about memory leaks. You have to try very hard to make that happen and will involve the DOM. You barely touch the DOM.

**Do not use Getters and Setters**

I have never understood why Javascript coders do this. Getters and Setters are for private properties that you do not have direct access to. They are too ensure a class's state is never compromised by vetting the the data when setting. It is to provide abstraction to data types when getting. They are for Object oriented languages, which Javascript is not and can never be.

There is no reason to use a getter when the value is as accessible as the getter call/ All you do is increase the work for the CPU in retrieving the getter reference, then pushing it onto the call stack, call the function, then get the value reference, move it to the return referance, the pop the call stack and return to the flow, get the return referance and move it to the variable we want it in.

It's so much quicker to just get the value reference, move it to the variable you want it in. Done. Javascript does not have private properties. The only way to have hidden properties is via closure, and you should only close over data that is not used outside its scope. Don't use them, and especially don't use them in games.

There is a lot more that can be optimised in your game (lots) but I think you have your hands full hunting down the cause of your frame inconsistency, also you game is only at 5% useage of the 1/60 frame time so you can ignore all I have said as you have all the time in the world.

Hope I did not sound to harsh. But it gets to me when I see that enthusiastic new programmers are picking up bad habits from old C++/C# Java coders who don't know how to use Javascript.

Comment: Wow thanks! I have a lot to look at and test. A majority of the code was just snippets from a javascript game development book that I was learning to make this game.

Comment: That's a nice explanation and I agree with most of it, except for one thing: "They are for Object oriented languages, which Javascript is not and can never be." JavaScript is very object-oriented; almost everything is an object. However, JS is an interpreted language, and it wasn't designed with data encapsulation in mind, plus it isn't a class-based language. Getters for private members need to be copied for each instance, which is very inefficient. If you want something to be "private", just put an underscore before or after its name instead. Then the getter can be a prototype-bound function

Comment: @Jacque For a language to be considered OO it must  not allow the production of code that does not fit the 3 tenets of OO design polymorphism, encapsulation, and inheritance. In Javascript encapsulation breaks inheritance and inheritance breaks encapsulation. The `_ ` means nothing, it's but a naming convention with no language defined meaning. Encapsulation is via closure , but closure  can not be inherited. How do I guarantee state when I can't protect my own class when allowing inheritance.

Comment: @Blindman67 Object oriented programming is just a programming paradigm - a way to write code. Forced encapsulation through language constructs such as a `private` keyword is just a tool some OOP languages provide. In Python, an underscore in front of a member means "private". It says so in the Python documentation and style guide. Yet the interpreter does nothing to enforce this, it's just a convention. You can do the same in JS and just accept that `_` means private. So what I meant to say is that **Javascript was designed to do OOP, but not to force or support encapsulation.**

Comment: @Jacque You miss the point of OO. It is not a design philosophy implementable in any general purpose state machine. It is about a guarantee regarding the possible states of my class, no matter what the environment, or how it is used it will NEVER fall outside its designed states. A solution to the Halting problem. Encapsulation is at the core of this guarantee, without it there is no guarantee and no OO  Javascript was not Designed to be OO it was designed to be like LISP and written in 10days by one man. OO programing is not about objects, it's about machine state management.

Comment: @Blindman67 I don't miss the point. We come for different programming backgrounds and it seems we have a different definition of the term OOP. I for one agree with this one: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/253093/175520